# Python - Toggling a connection to my local SOCKS proxy

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, tor

I am writing a crawler in Python that will run through Tor. I have Tor working and used code from [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDsmVH7eJCs) on how to route my Python requests to go through the Tor SOCKS proxy at `127.0.0.1:9050`.

What I can't figure out is how to toggle this on/off within my script. Some requests I want to go through Tor and some I don't. Basically, I can't figure out the correct "close" or "shutdown" method in the `socket` objects I am using because I don't understand them.

Here's what happens now

```
import socket
import socks
import requests

def connect_to_socks():
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', 9050, True)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket

r = requests.get('http://wtfismyip.com/text')
print r.text #prints my ordinary IP address
connect_to_socks()
r = requests.get('http://wtfismyip.com/text')
print r.text #prints my Tor IP address
```

How do I turn off the socket routing to the SOCKS proxy so that it goes through my ordinary internet connection?

I'm hoping to use `requests` instead of `urllib2` as it seems a lot easier but if I have to get into the guts of `urllib2` or even `httplib` I will. But would prefer not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out by listening to this [good YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3p-buQT72u0).

Just need to call `socket.setdefaultproxy()` and it brings me back.

Comment: Once you switch to Python 3.4, I recommend using urllib or httplib2 as both are very powerful and complete compared to requests.

Comment: U can also set to 0.0.0.0 and it would be threated as NULL; `socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '0.0.0.0', 9050, True)`
While this may appear unusefull, you can confuse people looking your code :) and let them think that 0.0.0.0 would work for any IP like it does when u put a interface listening to 0.0.0.0 :D

Comment: @kilgoretrout, shouldn't the call be socks.setdefaultproxy() 
Although using both `socket.setdefaultproxy()` and `socks.setdefaultproxy()` I'm not able to turn off the Tor socks5 proxy, any help?

Comment: @Shiv not sure what it’s “supposed” to be, but this worked for me

Comment: Ok with the your command, I got this error though
`
socket.setdefaultproxy()
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'setdefaultproxy'
`
I guess I'm using python3, thats why probably.

Comment: yeah could be a version issue, this is old

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3 you can set back default socket by using this:

```
socks.setdefaultproxy(None)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```